# Time series with r: dates aren't well ordered but df$var[order(df$Date)] only reorders var

Tags: r, datetime

I have a data set `PJMW` that contains two variables: `Datetime` and `PJMW_MW`. Datetime is of the form `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` and `PJMW_MW` are positive values that represent hourly energy consumption.

Here is a sample of the data:

```html
"2018-06-29 02:00:00", "2018-06-29 03:00:00", "2018-06-29 04:00:00", 
"2018-06-29 05:00:00", "2018-06-29 06:00:00", "2018-06-29 07:00:00", 
"2018-06-29 08:00:00", "2018-06-29 09:00:00", "2018-06-29 10:00:00", 
"2018-06-29 11:00:00", "2018-06-29 12:00:00", "2018-06-29 13:00:00", 
"2018-06-29 14:00:00", "2018-06-29 15:00:00", "2018-06-29 16:00:00", 
"2018-06-29 17:00:00", "2018-06-29 18:00:00", "2018-06-29 19:00:00", 
"2018-06-29 20:00:00", "2018-06-29 21:00:00", "2018-06-29 22:00:00", 
"2018-06-29 23:00:00", "2018-06-30 00:00:00", "2018-06-30 01:00:00", 
"2018-06-30 02:00:00", "2018-06-30 03:00:00", "2018-06-30 04:00:00", 
"2018-06-30 05:00:00", "2018-06-30 06:00:00", "2018-06-30 07:00:00", 
"2018-06-30 08:00:00", "2018-06-30 09:00:00", "2018-06-30 10:00:00", 
"2018-06-30 11:00:00", "2018-06-30 12:00:00", "2018-06-30 13:00:00", 
"2018-06-30 14:00:00", "2018-06-30 15:00:00", "2018-06-30 16:00:00", 
"2018-06-30 17:00:00", "2018-06-30 18:00:00", "2018-06-30 19:00:00", 
"2018-06-30 20:00:00", "2018-06-30 21:00:00", "2018-06-30 22:00:00", 
"2018-06-30 23:00:00", "2018-07-01 00:00:00", "2018-07-01 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-01 02:00:00", "2018-07-01 03:00:00", "2018-07-01 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-01 05:00:00", "2018-07-01 06:00:00", "2018-07-01 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-01 08:00:00", "2018-07-01 09:00:00", "2018-07-01 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-01 11:00:00", "2018-07-01 12:00:00", "2018-07-01 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-01 14:00:00", "2018-07-01 15:00:00", "2018-07-01 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-01 17:00:00", "2018-07-01 18:00:00", "2018-07-01 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-01 20:00:00", "2018-07-01 21:00:00", "2018-07-01 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-01 23:00:00", "2018-07-02 00:00:00", "2018-07-02 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-02 02:00:00", "2018-07-02 03:00:00", "2018-07-02 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-02 05:00:00", "2018-07-02 06:00:00", "2018-07-02 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-02 08:00:00", "2018-07-02 09:00:00", "2018-07-02 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-02 11:00:00", "2018-07-02 12:00:00", "2018-07-02 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-02 14:00:00", "2018-07-02 15:00:00", "2018-07-02 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-02 17:00:00", "2018-07-02 18:00:00", "2018-07-02 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-02 20:00:00", "2018-07-02 21:00:00", "2018-07-02 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-02 23:00:00", "2018-07-03 00:00:00", "2018-07-03 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-03 02:00:00", "2018-07-03 03:00:00", "2018-07-03 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-03 05:00:00", "2018-07-03 06:00:00", "2018-07-03 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-03 08:00:00", "2018-07-03 09:00:00", "2018-07-03 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-03 11:00:00", "2018-07-03 12:00:00", "2018-07-03 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-03 14:00:00", "2018-07-03 15:00:00", "2018-07-03 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-03 17:00:00", "2018-07-03 18:00:00", "2018-07-03 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-03 20:00:00", "2018-07-03 21:00:00", "2018-07-03 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-03 23:00:00", "2018-07-04 00:00:00", "2018-07-04 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-04 02:00:00", "2018-07-04 03:00:00", "2018-07-04 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-04 05:00:00", "2018-07-04 06:00:00", "2018-07-04 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-04 08:00:00", "2018-07-04 09:00:00", "2018-07-04 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-04 11:00:00", "2018-07-04 12:00:00", "2018-07-04 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-04 14:00:00", "2018-07-04 15:00:00", "2018-07-04 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-04 17:00:00", "2018-07-04 18:00:00", "2018-07-04 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-04 20:00:00", "2018-07-04 21:00:00", "2018-07-04 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-04 23:00:00", "2018-07-05 00:00:00", "2018-07-05 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-05 02:00:00", "2018-07-05 03:00:00", "2018-07-05 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-05 05:00:00", "2018-07-05 06:00:00", "2018-07-05 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-05 08:00:00", "2018-07-05 09:00:00", "2018-07-05 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-05 11:00:00", "2018-07-05 12:00:00", "2018-07-05 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-05 14:00:00", "2018-07-05 15:00:00", "2018-07-05 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-05 17:00:00", "2018-07-05 18:00:00", "2018-07-05 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-05 20:00:00", "2018-07-05 21:00:00", "2018-07-05 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-05 23:00:00", "2018-07-06 00:00:00", "2018-07-06 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-06 02:00:00", "2018-07-06 03:00:00", "2018-07-06 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-06 05:00:00", "2018-07-06 06:00:00", "2018-07-06 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-06 08:00:00", "2018-07-06 09:00:00", "2018-07-06 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-06 11:00:00", "2018-07-06 12:00:00", "2018-07-06 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-06 14:00:00", "2018-07-06 15:00:00", "2018-07-06 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-06 17:00:00", "2018-07-06 18:00:00", "2018-07-06 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-06 20:00:00", "2018-07-06 21:00:00", "2018-07-06 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-06 23:00:00", "2018-07-07 00:00:00", "2018-07-07 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-07 02:00:00", "2018-07-07 03:00:00", "2018-07-07 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-07 05:00:00", "2018-07-07 06:00:00", "2018-07-07 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-07 08:00:00", "2018-07-07 09:00:00", "2018-07-07 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-07 11:00:00", "2018-07-07 12:00:00", "2018-07-07 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-07 14:00:00", "2018-07-07 15:00:00", "2018-07-07 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-07 17:00:00", "2018-07-07 18:00:00", "2018-07-07 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-07 20:00:00", "2018-07-07 21:00:00", "2018-07-07 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-07 23:00:00", "2018-07-08 00:00:00", "2018-07-08 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-08 02:00:00", "2018-07-08 03:00:00", "2018-07-08 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-08 05:00:00", "2018-07-08 06:00:00", "2018-07-08 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-08 08:00:00", "2018-07-08 09:00:00", "2018-07-08 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-08 11:00:00", "2018-07-08 12:00:00", "2018-07-08 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-08 14:00:00", "2018-07-08 15:00:00", "2018-07-08 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-08 17:00:00", "2018-07-08 18:00:00", "2018-07-08 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-08 20:00:00", "2018-07-08 21:00:00", "2018-07-08 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-08 23:00:00", "2018-07-09 00:00:00", "2018-07-09 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-09 02:00:00", "2018-07-09 03:00:00", "2018-07-09 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-09 05:00:00", "2018-07-09 06:00:00", "2018-07-09 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-09 08:00:00", "2018-07-09 09:00:00", "2018-07-09 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-09 11:00:00", "2018-07-09 12:00:00", "2018-07-09 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-09 14:00:00", "2018-07-09 15:00:00", "2018-07-09 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-09 17:00:00", "2018-07-09 18:00:00", "2018-07-09 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-09 20:00:00", "2018-07-09 21:00:00", "2018-07-09 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-09 23:00:00", "2018-07-10 00:00:00", "2018-07-10 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-10 02:00:00", "2018-07-10 03:00:00", "2018-07-10 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-10 05:00:00", "2018-07-10 06:00:00", "2018-07-10 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-10 08:00:00", "2018-07-10 09:00:00", "2018-07-10 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-10 11:00:00", "2018-07-10 12:00:00", "2018-07-10 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-10 14:00:00", "2018-07-10 15:00:00", "2018-07-10 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-10 17:00:00", "2018-07-10 18:00:00", "2018-07-10 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-10 20:00:00", "2018-07-10 21:00:00", "2018-07-10 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-10 23:00:00", "2018-07-11 00:00:00", "2018-07-11 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-11 02:00:00", "2018-07-11 03:00:00", "2018-07-11 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-11 05:00:00", "2018-07-11 06:00:00", "2018-07-11 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-11 08:00:00", "2018-07-11 09:00:00", "2018-07-11 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-11 11:00:00", "2018-07-11 12:00:00", "2018-07-11 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-11 14:00:00", "2018-07-11 15:00:00", "2018-07-11 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-11 17:00:00", "2018-07-11 18:00:00", "2018-07-11 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-11 20:00:00", "2018-07-11 21:00:00", "2018-07-11 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-11 23:00:00", "2018-07-12 00:00:00", "2018-07-12 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-12 02:00:00", "2018-07-12 03:00:00", "2018-07-12 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-12 05:00:00", "2018-07-12 06:00:00", "2018-07-12 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-12 08:00:00", "2018-07-12 09:00:00", "2018-07-12 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-12 11:00:00", "2018-07-12 12:00:00", "2018-07-12 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-12 14:00:00", "2018-07-12 15:00:00", "2018-07-12 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-12 17:00:00", "2018-07-12 18:00:00", "2018-07-12 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-12 20:00:00", "2018-07-12 21:00:00", "2018-07-12 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-12 23:00:00", "2018-07-13 00:00:00", "2018-07-13 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-13 02:00:00", "2018-07-13 03:00:00", "2018-07-13 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-13 05:00:00", "2018-07-13 06:00:00", "2018-07-13 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-13 08:00:00", "2018-07-13 09:00:00", "2018-07-13 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-13 11:00:00", "2018-07-13 12:00:00", "2018-07-13 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-13 14:00:00", "2018-07-13 15:00:00", "2018-07-13 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-13 17:00:00", "2018-07-13 18:00:00", "2018-07-13 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-13 20:00:00", "2018-07-13 21:00:00", "2018-07-13 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-13 23:00:00", "2018-07-14 00:00:00", "2018-07-14 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-14 02:00:00", "2018-07-14 03:00:00", "2018-07-14 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-14 05:00:00", "2018-07-14 06:00:00", "2018-07-14 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-14 08:00:00", "2018-07-14 09:00:00", "2018-07-14 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-14 11:00:00", "2018-07-14 12:00:00", "2018-07-14 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-14 14:00:00", "2018-07-14 15:00:00", "2018-07-14 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-14 17:00:00", "2018-07-14 18:00:00", "2018-07-14 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-14 20:00:00", "2018-07-14 21:00:00", "2018-07-14 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-14 23:00:00", "2018-07-15 00:00:00", "2018-07-15 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-15 02:00:00", "2018-07-15 03:00:00", "2018-07-15 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-15 05:00:00", "2018-07-15 06:00:00", "2018-07-15 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-15 08:00:00", "2018-07-15 09:00:00", "2018-07-15 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-15 11:00:00", "2018-07-15 12:00:00", "2018-07-15 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-15 14:00:00", "2018-07-15 15:00:00", "2018-07-15 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-15 17:00:00", "2018-07-15 18:00:00", "2018-07-15 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-15 20:00:00", "2018-07-15 21:00:00", "2018-07-15 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-15 23:00:00", "2018-07-16 00:00:00", "2018-07-16 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-16 02:00:00", "2018-07-16 03:00:00", "2018-07-16 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-16 05:00:00", "2018-07-16 06:00:00", "2018-07-16 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-16 08:00:00", "2018-07-16 09:00:00", "2018-07-16 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-16 11:00:00", "2018-07-16 12:00:00", "2018-07-16 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-16 14:00:00", "2018-07-16 15:00:00", "2018-07-16 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-16 17:00:00", "2018-07-16 18:00:00", "2018-07-16 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-16 20:00:00", "2018-07-16 21:00:00", "2018-07-16 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-16 23:00:00", "2018-07-17 00:00:00", "2018-07-17 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-17 02:00:00", "2018-07-17 03:00:00", "2018-07-17 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-17 05:00:00", "2018-07-17 06:00:00", "2018-07-17 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-17 08:00:00", "2018-07-17 09:00:00", "2018-07-17 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-17 11:00:00", "2018-07-17 12:00:00", "2018-07-17 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-17 14:00:00", "2018-07-17 15:00:00", "2018-07-17 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-17 17:00:00", "2018-07-17 18:00:00", "2018-07-17 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-17 20:00:00", "2018-07-17 21:00:00", "2018-07-17 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-17 23:00:00", "2018-07-18 00:00:00", "2018-07-18 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-18 02:00:00", "2018-07-18 03:00:00", "2018-07-18 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-18 05:00:00", "2018-07-18 06:00:00", "2018-07-18 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-18 08:00:00", "2018-07-18 09:00:00", "2018-07-18 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-18 11:00:00", "2018-07-18 12:00:00", "2018-07-18 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-18 14:00:00", "2018-07-18 15:00:00", "2018-07-18 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-18 17:00:00", "2018-07-18 18:00:00", "2018-07-18 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-18 20:00:00", "2018-07-18 21:00:00", "2018-07-18 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-18 23:00:00", "2018-07-19 00:00:00", "2018-07-19 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-19 02:00:00", "2018-07-19 03:00:00", "2018-07-19 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-19 05:00:00", "2018-07-19 06:00:00", "2018-07-19 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-19 08:00:00", "2018-07-19 09:00:00", "2018-07-19 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-19 11:00:00", "2018-07-19 12:00:00", "2018-07-19 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-19 14:00:00", "2018-07-19 15:00:00", "2018-07-19 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-19 17:00:00", "2018-07-19 18:00:00", "2018-07-19 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-19 20:00:00", "2018-07-19 21:00:00", "2018-07-19 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-19 23:00:00", "2018-07-20 00:00:00", "2018-07-20 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-20 02:00:00", "2018-07-20 03:00:00", "2018-07-20 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-20 05:00:00", "2018-07-20 06:00:00", "2018-07-20 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-20 08:00:00", "2018-07-20 09:00:00", "2018-07-20 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-20 11:00:00", "2018-07-20 12:00:00", "2018-07-20 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-20 14:00:00", "2018-07-20 15:00:00", "2018-07-20 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-20 17:00:00", "2018-07-20 18:00:00", "2018-07-20 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-20 20:00:00", "2018-07-20 21:00:00", "2018-07-20 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-20 23:00:00", "2018-07-21 00:00:00", "2018-07-21 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-21 02:00:00", "2018-07-21 03:00:00", "2018-07-21 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-21 05:00:00", "2018-07-21 06:00:00", "2018-07-21 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-21 08:00:00", "2018-07-21 09:00:00", "2018-07-21 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-21 11:00:00", "2018-07-21 12:00:00", "2018-07-21 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-21 14:00:00", "2018-07-21 15:00:00", "2018-07-21 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-21 17:00:00", "2018-07-21 18:00:00", "2018-07-21 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-21 20:00:00", "2018-07-21 21:00:00", "2018-07-21 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-21 23:00:00", "2018-07-22 00:00:00", "2018-07-22 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-22 02:00:00", "2018-07-22 03:00:00", "2018-07-22 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-22 05:00:00", "2018-07-22 06:00:00", "2018-07-22 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-22 08:00:00", "2018-07-22 09:00:00", "2018-07-22 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-22 11:00:00", "2018-07-22 12:00:00", "2018-07-22 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-22 14:00:00", "2018-07-22 15:00:00", "2018-07-22 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-22 17:00:00", "2018-07-22 18:00:00", "2018-07-22 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-22 20:00:00", "2018-07-22 21:00:00", "2018-07-22 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-22 23:00:00", "2018-07-23 00:00:00", "2018-07-23 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-23 02:00:00", "2018-07-23 03:00:00", "2018-07-23 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-23 05:00:00", "2018-07-23 06:00:00", "2018-07-23 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-23 08:00:00", "2018-07-23 09:00:00", "2018-07-23 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-23 11:00:00", "2018-07-23 12:00:00", "2018-07-23 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-23 14:00:00", "2018-07-23 15:00:00", "2018-07-23 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-23 17:00:00", "2018-07-23 18:00:00", "2018-07-23 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-23 20:00:00", "2018-07-23 21:00:00", "2018-07-23 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-23 23:00:00", "2018-07-24 00:00:00", "2018-07-24 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-24 02:00:00", "2018-07-24 03:00:00", "2018-07-24 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-24 05:00:00", "2018-07-24 06:00:00", "2018-07-24 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-24 08:00:00", "2018-07-24 09:00:00", "2018-07-24 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-24 11:00:00", "2018-07-24 12:00:00", "2018-07-24 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-24 14:00:00", "2018-07-24 15:00:00", "2018-07-24 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-24 17:00:00", "2018-07-24 18:00:00", "2018-07-24 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-24 20:00:00", "2018-07-24 21:00:00", "2018-07-24 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-24 23:00:00", "2018-07-25 00:00:00", "2018-07-25 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-25 02:00:00", "2018-07-25 03:00:00", "2018-07-25 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-25 05:00:00", "2018-07-25 06:00:00", "2018-07-25 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-25 08:00:00", "2018-07-25 09:00:00", "2018-07-25 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-25 11:00:00", "2018-07-25 12:00:00", "2018-07-25 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-25 14:00:00", "2018-07-25 15:00:00", "2018-07-25 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-25 17:00:00", "2018-07-25 18:00:00", "2018-07-25 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-25 20:00:00", "2018-07-25 21:00:00", "2018-07-25 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-25 23:00:00", "2018-07-26 00:00:00", "2018-07-26 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-26 02:00:00", "2018-07-26 03:00:00", "2018-07-26 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-26 05:00:00", "2018-07-26 06:00:00", "2018-07-26 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-26 08:00:00", "2018-07-26 09:00:00", "2018-07-26 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-26 11:00:00", "2018-07-26 12:00:00", "2018-07-26 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-26 14:00:00", "2018-07-26 15:00:00", "2018-07-26 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-26 17:00:00", "2018-07-26 18:00:00", "2018-07-26 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-26 20:00:00", "2018-07-26 21:00:00", "2018-07-26 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-26 23:00:00", "2018-07-27 00:00:00", "2018-07-27 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-27 02:00:00", "2018-07-27 03:00:00", "2018-07-27 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-27 05:00:00", "2018-07-27 06:00:00", "2018-07-27 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-27 08:00:00", "2018-07-27 09:00:00", "2018-07-27 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-27 11:00:00", "2018-07-27 12:00:00", "2018-07-27 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-27 14:00:00", "2018-07-27 15:00:00", "2018-07-27 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-27 17:00:00", "2018-07-27 18:00:00", "2018-07-27 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-27 20:00:00", "2018-07-27 21:00:00", "2018-07-27 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-27 23:00:00", "2018-07-28 00:00:00", "2018-07-28 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-28 02:00:00", "2018-07-28 03:00:00", "2018-07-28 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-28 05:00:00", "2018-07-28 06:00:00", "2018-07-28 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-28 08:00:00", "2018-07-28 09:00:00", "2018-07-28 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-28 11:00:00", "2018-07-28 12:00:00", "2018-07-28 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-28 14:00:00", "2018-07-28 15:00:00", "2018-07-28 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-28 17:00:00", "2018-07-28 18:00:00", "2018-07-28 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-28 20:00:00", "2018-07-28 21:00:00", "2018-07-28 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-28 23:00:00", "2018-07-29 00:00:00", "2018-07-29 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-29 02:00:00", "2018-07-29 03:00:00", "2018-07-29 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-29 05:00:00", "2018-07-29 06:00:00", "2018-07-29 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-29 08:00:00", "2018-07-29 09:00:00", "2018-07-29 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-29 11:00:00", "2018-07-29 12:00:00", "2018-07-29 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-29 14:00:00", "2018-07-29 15:00:00", "2018-07-29 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-29 17:00:00", "2018-07-29 18:00:00", "2018-07-29 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-29 20:00:00", "2018-07-29 21:00:00", "2018-07-29 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-29 23:00:00", "2018-07-30 00:00:00", "2018-07-30 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-30 02:00:00", "2018-07-30 03:00:00", "2018-07-30 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-30 05:00:00", "2018-07-30 06:00:00", "2018-07-30 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-30 08:00:00", "2018-07-30 09:00:00", "2018-07-30 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-30 11:00:00", "2018-07-30 12:00:00", "2018-07-30 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-30 14:00:00", "2018-07-30 15:00:00", "2018-07-30 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-30 17:00:00", "2018-07-30 18:00:00", "2018-07-30 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-30 20:00:00", "2018-07-30 21:00:00", "2018-07-30 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-30 23:00:00", "2018-07-31 00:00:00", "2018-07-31 01:00:00", 
"2018-07-31 02:00:00", "2018-07-31 03:00:00", "2018-07-31 04:00:00", 
"2018-07-31 05:00:00", "2018-07-31 06:00:00", "2018-07-31 07:00:00", 
"2018-07-31 08:00:00", "2018-07-31 09:00:00", "2018-07-31 10:00:00", 
"2018-07-31 11:00:00", "2018-07-31 12:00:00", "2018-07-31 13:00:00", 
"2018-07-31 14:00:00", "2018-07-31 15:00:00", "2018-07-31 16:00:00", 
"2018-07-31 17:00:00", "2018-07-31 18:00:00", "2018-07-31 19:00:00", 
"2018-07-31 20:00:00", "2018-07-31 21:00:00", "2018-07-31 22:00:00", 
"2018-07-31 23:00:00", "2018-08-01 00:00:00", "2018-08-01 01:00:00", 
"2018-08-01 02:00:00", "2018-08-01 03:00:00", "2018-08-01 04:00:00", 
"2018-08-01 05:00:00", "2018-08-01 06:00:00", "2018-08-01 07:00:00", 
"2018-08-01 08:00:00", "2018-08-01 09:00:00", "2018-08-01 10:00:00", 
"2018-08-01 11:00:00", "2018-08-01 12:00:00", "2018-08-01 13:00:00", 
"2018-08-01 14:00:00", "2018-08-01 15:00:00", "2018-08-01 16:00:00", 
"2018-08-01 17:00:00", "2018-08-01 18:00:00", "2018-08-01 19:00:00", 
"2018-08-01 20:00:00", "2018-08-01 21:00:00", "2018-08-01 22:00:00", 
"2018-08-01 23:00:00", "2018-08-02 00:00:00", "2018-08-02 01:00:00", 
"2018-08-02 02:00:00", "2018-08-02 03:00:00", "2018-08-02 04:00:00", 
"2018-08-02 05:00:00", "2018-08-02 06:00:00", "2018-08-02 07:00:00", 
"2018-08-02 08:00:00", "2018-08-02 09:00:00", "2018-08-02 10:00:00", 
"2018-08-02 11:00:00", "2018-08-02 12:00:00", "2018-08-02 13:00:00", 
"2018-08-02 14:00:00", "2018-08-02 15:00:00", "2018-08-02 16:00:00", 
"2018-08-02 17:00:00", "2018-08-02 18:00:00", "2018-08-02 19:00:00", 
"2018-08-02 20:00:00", "2018-08-02 21:00:00", "2018-08-02 22:00:00", 
"2018-08-02 23:00:00", "2018-08-03 00:00:00"), class = "factor"), 
    PJMW_MW = c(5077, 4939, 4885, 4857, 4930, 5126), newDate = structure(c(12052, 
    12052, 12052, 12052, 12052, 12052), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

You can find the whole thing at [Kaggle.com](https://www.kaggle.com/robikscube/hourly-energy-consumption#PJMW_hourly.csv)

As you can se time is moving forward when it comes to hours and years but not days and months.

I would like to have everything well ordered *i.e.* Datetime, PJMW_MW and the indices. I tried using `PJMW$PJMW_MW[order(PJMW$Datetime)]` and it works but it only orders `PJMW_MW`.

Comment: Are your dates `Date` objects generated with `as.Date` or a `lubridate::` function, or just strings (type `character`)? They appear to be using string ordering, not date formatting

Comment: `> typeof(PJMW_hourly$Datetime)
[1] "integer"` returns that they are of integer type

Comment: Can you include a [mcve] of your data in text, not image format. Use `dupt(PJMW_hourly)`, or `dput(head(PJMW_hourly))` if that's too long, and paste the results into the question. Using `class` will be more helpful since Date is a class, not a type

Comment: What is dupt? It's not in the documentation. 

`> class(PJMW_hourly$Datetime)
[1] "factor"` so it is a factor

Comment: I mean the whole data is on Kaggle. Should I paste a few rows? Because there is no code to show here, so I don't know what to put in the Minimal complete and verifiable example

Comment: That's your problem. A `factor` is not a date. It is just an integer which associates values with character labels in an arbitrary order. If you want to order properly by date, you need to convert `Datetime` to `character` then to `Date`. And yes, the recommendation here is that all information we need to answer the question be in the question, not in off site links or images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order the whole data.frame like this

```
PJMW[order(PJMW$Datetime) , ]
```